# nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:12

Tags: laravel, docker

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  webserver:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx_cont
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    depends_on:
      - app
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.laravel
    image: laravel
    container_name: laravel_cont
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./src/config/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/public;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Docker.nginx

```
FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /etc/nginx/conf.d

COPY ./nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf

COPY . /var/www
```

Running via docker-compose up and getting this error:

/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_cont   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx_cont   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx_cont   | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
nginx_cont   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_cont   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx_cont   | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx_cont   | 2022/06/07 11:25:24 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:12
nginx_cont   | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "php" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf:12

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You named your PHP container `app` and you need to use that name in the `fastcgi_pass` URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
     - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
```

Try to replace the line on
docker-compose.yaml with the above

on the

```
volume
```